# How to upload image and receive data input in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, multipartform-data, node-modules

I use mutter and body-parser to upload image and transfer file type multipart/form-data.
I have a form to upload and save name image to database, i want when not choose file in form , i still receive data of text input another. 
This is my form :

```
<form action="/upload?_csrf=<%= csrf %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
            <input type="text" name="name" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Save"> </form>
```

Comment: trying to decipher your question ... Do you want to submit the form even without a file being "selected"? Is that the "issue"?

Comment: Can you clarify "i want when not choose file in form , i still receive data of text input another"?

Comment: Its mean, the problem is when i don't upload image, i don't received the name data in body params when i submit form.

Comment: @jaromadaX right

Comment: That's not a problem. If the user doesn't select a file, and doesn't fill in the name input, submit won't send any data. Clarify what you want to do, what you expect and what happens.

Comment: Step by step as bellow
1) user enter name in textfield. Ex: SonStony \n
2) user don't select image file \n
3) user click on submit \n
4) on server i don't receive the name that user entered. \n
is it clarify for you?